# Generalizing multiple get functions in JS

Tags: javascript, function

I have a JS class that has a bunch of get methods, that all have the same structure for calling a JSON object value, how can I generalize this function as to not have to write a method for every get function since I need hundreds of these with the same code.

```
get Health() {
    var temp = this._foods[this._foodID].Health;
    return  temp === undefined ? 0 : temp;
};

get HealthRegen() {
    var temp = this._foods[this._foodID].HealthRegen;
    return  temp === undefined ? 0 : temp;
};
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like a XY problem. Why would you need to replicate all the data in another object?

Comment: I simplified the code to the bare minimum for it to be understandable, the function gets more complex, but one of the answers with a proxy seems to solve all of my problems, thanks for commenting tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) on the `this._foods` object like this :

```js
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
        this._foodID = 1;
        this._foods = {
            1: {
                Health: 1,
                HealthRegen: 1
            },
            2: {
                Health: 2
            },
        };
        this.proxy = new Proxy(this._foods, {
            get: (object, key) => {
                const value = object[this._foodID][key];
                return value === undefined ? 0 : value;
            }
        });
    }

    someMethod() {
      console.log('someMethod call')
    }
}

const someInstance = new SomeClass();
console.log(someInstance._foodID);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.Health);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.HealthRegen);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.UndefinedProperty);
someInstance._foodID = 2;
console.log(someInstance._foodID);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.Health);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.HealthRegen);
console.log(someInstance.proxy.UndefinedProperty);
someInstance.someMethod()
```

Comment: This is amazing, and solves so many of my problems, thank you so much!

Comment: Using this object:
this._foods = {
    "a": {
        Health: 1,
        HealthRegen: 1
    },
    "b": {
        Health: 2
    }
};
And these commands, i get the wrong answer for b, how come?
someInstance._foodID = "b";
console.log(someInstance.proxy.Health);

Comment: so i figured it out, you passed the id when creating the proxy, whcih singles out one food, but if you use the id within the proxy it uses the activer variable

Answer (score -1):

Define a method that takes the property name as a parameter, and call it from each of the getters.

```
_getProp(propname) {
  var temp = this._foods[this.__foodId][propname];
  return temp === undefined ? 0 : temp;
}

get Health() {
  return this._getProp("Health");
};

get HealthRegen() {
  return this._getProp("HealthRegen");
};
```